How to expect-type of value returned by context
I have a context provider providing an object that I want to test the type of, how do I get this to compare the type of the given value. I am currently attempting to use the expect-type library, but that is unable to detect differences. I will accept any answer that gives me a way to confirm the type matches what I am expecting.
import { MyBigType } from './TextResources';
import { MyContext } from './TextContext';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { expectTypeOf } from 'expect-type';

describe('MyBigType ', () => {

  // If I include the MyBigType label it always passes, if not it always fails
  let myBigObject : MyBigType ;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Get the text resources before each test
    const TestWrapper = () => {
      // this is the best way I have found to pull the value from a context provider
      myBigObject = useContext(MyContext);
      return null;
    };
    render(<TestWrapper />);
  });

  test('should match MyContext with MyBigType', () => {
    
    expectTypeOf(myBigObject ).toEqualTypeOf<MyBigType>();
  });
});


What's the issue, what do you expect? Please clarify

The return type of useContext is always just the generic, so you don't need to actually call the function if you just want to test the type - adapt e.g. this answer to get the generic straight out of MyContext, that's what the return type of useContext(MyContext) would be. https://tsplay.dev/w1DZlW

@johnsharpe The thing I am trying to test is whether the type that is actually returned at runtime is the same as the type the context is supposed to return.

Then expect-type/toEqualTypeOf doesn't make a lot of sense; that's a compile-time type check, not for the value (the runtime implementation doesn't do anything, _actual is ignored). Surely if you were setting the wrong type into the context, you'd get a compiler error at that point.

@jonrsharpe The big object in question is a language file, defined outside of ts. After talking to a coworker, we decided that a unit test was not the correct approach, instead it would be better to try to automate the creation of the type definition, which is not inside the scope of this problem.

This is not possible in vanilla TypeScript. Types are not available at runtime (source), including to unit testing frameworks. The expectTypeOf() function uses the built in static type checker to compare the indicated type to the type of the given parameter. Because the structure of myBigObject is only available at runtime and the type of MyBigType is only available at compile time, the two cannot be compared directly.
In terms of non vanilla typescript, the typia library can compare things by running a transformer during the compilations process. Transforming a TypeScript type to a runtime function.
